How to have a blur effect with Paint()
I would like to recreate the blurring effect that is done by BackdropFilter
ClipRect(
              child: BackdropFilter(
                filter: ui.ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 15, sigmaY: 15),
                child: Container(
                  width: 300,
                  height: 300,
                ),
              ),
            ),

using Canvas. What I am doing now is
Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..imageFilter = ui.ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 15, sigmaY: 15)
      ..blendMode = BlendMode.srcOver;

but the effect is not the same as the one made by BackdropFilter.



creating a Paint object will not change anything - you need to draw your image on the canvas - most likely you have to call Canvas.drawImageRect method

yeah I am doing it like this for (var face in faceDetected) {       canvas.drawRect(face.boundingBox, paint);     }, but is paint that defines what is painted

so post another image with the result you got with your CustomPaint - btw why dont you use BackdropFilter if its result is ok to you?

btw if you really use drawRect it will draw just rect - it will not blur the image you drew before with drawImage method

i don't use BackdropFilter because my goal is to manipulate the image and draw the blurring rectangle on the bytes, and not place Widget above the original image

i updated the pictures btw.

ok, as i said "drawRect it will draw just rect - it will not blur the image you drew before with drawImage method " - you need drawImageRect instead

ok, but then how? with drawImageRect?

canvas.drawImageRect(image, face.boundingBox, face.boundingBox, paint);

love u!!!!!!!!!
